# what does this mean? (about class and instance)

Tags: c#, class, instance

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        haha haha1;
    }
}

class haha
{
    int a;
    int b;

    public haha(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

I know if I want make instance, I should write code such as:

```
haha haha1 = new haha(1,2);
```

but when I write just

```
haha haha1;
```

there's no compile error.

What does `haha haha1;` mean? isn't it wrong code?

Answer (score 4):

It is not wrong code. It is a variable declaration.

```
haha haha1;
```

simply declares a variable named haha1 which has the type haha. However this variable was not assigned a value.

When you instantiate the object with the new keyword:

```
haha1 = new haha();
```

the variable then refers to the object created

Comment: Also: if you declare an object-variable and do not wish to create the object at that time, I suggest that you should assign it the value `null`, *e.g. `haha haha1 = null;'`.  In this way, you not only *emphasize* (to the human reader) what you are doing, but you also ensure that the value of the variable will never initially contain "garbage."  I like to do the same thing, as often as it makes sense, with pointer-variables, too.

Comment: @MikeRobinson It is a compile error to refer to an uninitialized (local) variable in C#, so there's no way to read garbage (class fields are initialized by default so they still can never be garbage).  By always initializing variables (especially with null) you can cover up problems where your code assumes the value has been initialized correctly.  Leaving it uninitialized would allow the compiler to detect these issues.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  *That* they kept from Delphi!  Yours is an excellent point, which I have duly up-voted.  I yield my previous recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the programming language, but most programming languages choose one of two options:

1) Implicit initialization (C++)

```
haha haha1;
```

is the same as

```
haha haha1 = new haha1();
```

2) Null initialization (C#)

```
haha haha1;
```

is the same as

```
haha haha1 = null;
```

Whatever happens, the result of the behavior is called the "default value" or "default initializer". Refer to your language documentation for details.

Some notes: C and C++ allows variables to be uninitialized, so they have no determinate value until you assign to them. C++ non-pointers cannot be NULL, so they are always initialized with something (but everything else, including pointers, follows the C rule).

Comment: `haha haha1` is only equivalent to a null assignment if `haha1` is a field in a class.  Local variables can be uninitialized and this is different from initializing them to `null` since the compiler won't allow you to read from local variables that aren't definitely assigned.

Comment: @Kyle which language are you referring to?

Comment: @andlabs Well, the question was tagged C#, so I'm referring to C#.

Comment: @Kyle ah, I see someone added the tag after I posted the answer. Didn't know that about C#; good to know!